# AngularJs #how to pass scope variable in on change event in directive in input file

Tags: html, angularjs

I am not able to pass data to controller's function through angular directive, directive has one change event. In which i want to pass my dynamic id.
In controller i have myArray

```
$scope.myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I have following html.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myArray track by $index">
    <input type="file" ng-upload-change="uploadFile($event, $id)" my-id="$index">
<div>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function($event, $id){
    var files = $event.target.files;
    console.log("id:"+$id);
};
```

In directive:

```
app.directive('ngUploadChange', function() {
    return{
        scope:{
            ngUploadChange:"&",
            myId:"="
        },
        link:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $element.on("change",function(event){
                $scope.ngUploadChange({$event: event, $id : $scope.myId});
            })
            $scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
                $element.off();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see that when i pass uploadFile function to ngUploadChange directive, it always pass first id (in this case it is 1) to controllers function.
I am not getting updated id every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your problem in fiddle, and I get the updated Ids always. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28624/), check what is missing apart from your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pass parameters through the function, you can use `"="` instead of `"&"` for that attr binding, and in your HTML, you can specify like this:

```
<input type="file" ng-upload-change="uploadFile" ... />
```

And, I changed the way you were passing an object of params since there is no need to create that object.

Now, if you see the code snippet below, it correctly logs `id: x` (0-based) on each file upload.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.uploadFile = function($event, $id) {
    var files = $event.target.files;
    console.log("id: " + $id);
  };
});

myApp.directive('ngUploadChange', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngUploadChange: "=",
      myId: "="
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.on("change", function(event) {
        $scope.ngUploadChange(event, $scope.myId);
      })
      $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        $element.off();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in myArray">
    <input type="file" ng-upload-change="uploadFile" my-id="$index">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to write the directive without isolate scope.

```
app.directive('ngUploadChange', function() {
    return{
        /*
        scope:{
            ngUploadChange:"&",
            myId:"="
        },*/
        link:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $element.on("change",function(event){
                var locals = { $event: event,
                               $id : $scope.$eval($attrs.myId)
                }; 
                $scope.$eval($attrs.ngUploadChange, locals);
            });
            /*
            $scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
                $element.off();
            });*/
        }
    }
});
```

Use [$scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) instead of isolate scope bindings.

Isolate scope adds a scope and additional watchers which have been known to cause digest cycle delays that fight the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).